RabbitMQ find stuck consumers
I've managed to write a simple Python script to get some basic metrics from my queues. But this is not enough to detect if one of my consumers is not processing tasks.
Is there any way to get deliver_get but for each consumer?
Thanks
import requests
import json

url = "http://localhost:15672/api/queues"
username = "user"
password = "pass"

response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))

if response.status_code == 200:

    queues_data = response.json()
    processed_data = []

    for queue in queues_data:
        queue_name = queue.get("name", "")
        if queue_name == "my_queue":
            queue_info = {
                "queue": queue_name,
                "tasks_in_progress": queue.get("messages_unacknowledged"),
                "tasks_processed": queue.get("message_stats", {}).get("deliver_get"),
                "consumers": queue.get("consumers")
            }
            processed_data.append(queue_info)

    print(json.dumps(processed_data, indent=2))

else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")

# python3 /tmp/t.py 
[
  {
    "queue": "my_queue",
    "tasks_in_progress": 6,
    "tasks_processed": 34158338,
    "consumers": 6
  }
]

